# Como criar elemento pai?

Tags: jquery

Como criar uma tag pai dentro de um elemento com jQuery, por exemplo, tendo essa estrutura original:

```html
<p>texto</p>
```

Após a função jQuery ficaria desta forma:

```html
<a href='#'>
    <p>texto</p>
</a>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Podes fazer assim:

```js
$('p').wrapAll('<a href="#" />');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>texto</p>
```

Comment: Show cara, muito obrigado!

Comment: De nada @TalesBreno